# Dynamic Programming:optimal Binary search tree and Huffman

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming, huffman-code

Is it possible to construct an optimal Binary search tree (OBST) via a greedy algorithm instead of with Dynamic Programming (DP) (for example Huffman's algorithm)? If so why is DP is preferred in the construction of a OBST?

Comment: You need to put little more effort if you are expecting an answer

Comment: Huffman codes can be designed in any order -- the optimal greedy algorithm can pair up any two aggregated subtrees.  However, a binary search tree needs to be in search order:  you can't pick any two subtrees, they have to be next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

There are no efficient greedy algorithms to always construct an **optimal** binary search tree. However there are likely to be heuristics such as greedy algorithms that construct nearly optimal trees, which may be preferable in practice.